# Not able to push data from one view controller to a table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, viewcontroller

I ran into a strange problem while I was working on my project. (Please bear with me, I'm a Swift beginner.)

This is what my storyboard looks like so far.
[On the left is my regular view controller, and on the right is the TableViewController. the transition inbetween has a specific ID.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OUS8.png)

```
**This is the first View Controller.**

class TestsMenuViewController: UIViewController {
var tests = [Test]() 
var testTableViewController : TestsTableViewController?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tests = DataModel().patientData
    //this just populates the array with some data.
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "testTableTransition" {
        testTableViewController = segue.destination as? TestsTableViewController
        testTableViewController?.tests = self.tests
        print(testTableViewController?.tests[0].testDescription)
        //somehow this is an empty array
    }
}
```

somehow the test array does not get passed to the next controller :( what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `print(self.tests)` in you prepareForSegue method and check whether is there any value in it or not

Comment: it returns nothing. if i print the statement in the viewdidload, then it gives me back some value. however, if i do the same print statement in the prepare for segue method, it gives me back nothing :/

Comment: are you sure you are getting value here `self.tests = DataModel().patientData` ?

Comment: put `super.viewDidLoad()` before `self.tests = DataModel().patientData` and then check

Comment: yes, im sure im getting a value! i also tried putting super.viewDidLoad before the rest, but then it would just load an empty table view. is there some option to reload the tableviewcontroller or something?

Comment: self.tableView.reloadData is the method through which you can reload tableView

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like but as long as you don't do anything with self.tests before your code come to prepare(for: segue: ) then I don't see anything wrong with it. I would try to add a break point on the line testTableViewController?.tests = self.tests and print out self.tests to check if the array still exist or still has data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I managed to solve my problem, what I just did was initialize the data that I pass to the TableViewController directly in the attributes. Then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You could save the data as NSUserDefaults and call the saved data to the view when you want